# Usage of new and traits in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I've found usage of the following in Scala examples, but I can't find proper reference (probably because Google gets confused by `new` and `with` that are very common words...):

```
var someInstance = new Class with SomeTrait
```

In the basic documentation about traits I couldn't find anything...

Comment: See: [Compound types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/compound-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... its a way to create instances of Anonymous class.

So,

```
trait A

trait B

class C extends A

val cb = new C with B
// creates an instance of anonymous class 'C with B'
```

is same as,

```
trait A

trait B

class C extends A

class D extends C with B

val d = new D
// creates an instance of class 'D'
```

Now, `cb` and `d` both will have same properties.

Comment: Did you mean class D extends C with B ?

Comment: I see, it's just an extension of C without the {}. I'm coming from Java and sometimes I get confused by this kind of short-hands